# Ember-cli coffescript generators for resource

Tags: coffeescript, ember-cli

I installed `ember-cli-coffeescript` on my ember app ,renamed my `router.js` file to `router.coffee`(and replaced its code with coffee) and then I run

`ember generate resource ingredients`.

I got an error  saying

```
no such file or directory '<path-to-app>/<my-app>/app/router.js'
```

This happens only when I'm trying to generate a resource. When trying to generate a route all is working perfectly, a route is being added inside my `router.coffee` file and the route and template files are being generated perfectly as coffee.

Is there a solution to this so to generate resources with coffescript?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like when you generate a route or resource you need to be the directory 
'/'

```
<path-to-app>/<my-app>
```

instead of

```
<path-to-app>/<my-app>/app
```

looking into why, but that's the issue

<UPDATE>

known issue

from ember-cli [#2116](https://github.com/stefanpenner/ember-cli/issues/2116)

they've put it on ember-cli-coffeescript(ember-cli doesn't support coffeescript generators) [#21](https://github.com/kimroen/ember-cli-coffeescript/issues/21)

Comment: thanks for your answer. I also got an answer in github https://github.com/kimroen/ember-cli-coffeescript/issues/21#issuecomment-59054536